# Minimize Firefox to system tray in Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, notification-area

I wish to minimize Firefox to system tray. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MinimizeToTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) extension should be what you want.

[image]

Comment: I love that tool. You just right click on minimize and it goes to the systray.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in the `70.0.1 (64-bit)` Version of the *Mozilla* *Firefox* Web-Browser, the [*MinimizeToTray*](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/firefox/addon/minimizetotray/) Extension does not work any longer.

Subsequent attempts to revive it, called as [*MinimizeToTray Revived*](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) and  [*MinimizeToTray Reanimated*](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-reanimated/) are also no longer working.

Also, Software Utilities such as [*RBTray*](http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/) or [*xtraButtons*](http://www.xtrabuttons.com/) are unable to minimize it to the System Tray, as it is different than other Static Software Applications in respect to its Minimize Button.

[image: The Minimize Button of the Mozilla Firefox Web-Browser]

The solution that we have found to this intricate situation has been to install another Software Utility also called as [*MinimizeToTray*](https://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/Minimize-ToTray.shtml) that is able to minimize *any* Static Software Application to the System Tray, even our tricky *Mozilla* *Firefox* Web-Browser.

[image: The MinimizeToTray Static Software Application in the System Tray]